# Is QGIS Server's PDF output georeferenced?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, pdf, qgis-server, geospatial-pdf

QGIS Server supports the `GetPrint` `WMS` request and for it, the `pdf` output format: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/services/wms.html#wms-getprint-format

Is this a [Geospatial PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geospatial_PDF) or a plain "dumb" PDF?

Comment: I see that a CRS is required.  What does gdalinfo return on one of your exported PDFs?

Comment: I don't have a QGIS server instance right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create georeferenced PDFs with QGIS Server's GetPrint Request, but it's not possible to create GeoPDFs with layers included.

If you enable "Append georeference information" in the layout PDF export and store the QGIS project afterwards, QGIS Server will remember this setting in all GetPrint requests of the certain layout.